# Geometric Relationships

Tags: geometry

So basically I thought of this problem and although my friend and I figured out an answer, it was pretty messy and I want to know if there's a better way to do it. 
Here's my fantastic ms paint diagram of it. I'll do all the pronumerals at the bottom.

[image]

x is the length along the top (constant, until you get the the bonus points)

z is the angle between x and y

h is the height from the corner between x and h down to where y intersects h

The question is:
Find an equation that describes the relationship between z and y (or h, they're synonymous). For extra points (and probably best answer), show how if you increase x by an amount, what will happen to the other pronumerals (so show that in comparison to the original).

Sorry for the bad wording; I'm not very good at putting my thoughts into words. And by the way, is there any particular conventions around what pronumerals you should use where?

Thanks

Comment: You have a right triangle there so $\sin z=h/y$.

Comment: Yeah that's what I came up with but I was wondering if there was a method that allowed for more comparison between different z sizes